# How to cancel commands in emacs before applying it?

Tags: linux, emacs

I am new to emacs, and I am not sure if such operation is allowed.
If I type in C-c, for example, can I cancel it before implementing it(like type in C-w afterwards).
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always press `Esc Esc Esc` or `M-Esc Esc` which by default is bound to `keyboard-escape-quit`

Comment: However, `Esc Esc Esc` unsplits a split window (after `C-x 3`), which `C-g` doesn't.

Answer (score 11):

As I understand it, `C-g` cancels anything at any time.

[Source: gnu.org/.../emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html)

Comment: That is true if you press C-x -b and then you want to quit. In that situation C-g works. In the case of my question, emacs just reminds C-c C-g is not defined.

Comment: Well, it reminds you AND aborts the command, so mission accomplished, isn't it?

Comment: well, your words make sense.:)

Comment: In the docs section **Quitting and Aborting**: _Quitting with ‘C-g’ is the way to get rid of a partially typed command, or a numeric argument that you don’t want._